# Regarding dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

I've a dropdownlist which is designed using html select tag. the thing is its working fine in ie and not working in mozilla, opera and google chrome... can any one help.. the code used is

```
<select name="select nav" size="1" style="background-color:#FFFFFF" onChange="location.href=options[selectedIndex].value;">
                                    <option value="locations_aberdeen.html">Aberdeen
                                    <option value="locations_arendal.html" selected>Arendal
                                    <option value="locations_athens.html">Athens
                                    <option value="locations_bangkok.html">Bangkok
                                    <option value="locations_beijing.html">Beijing
                                    <option value="locations_capetown.html">Capetown
                                    <option value="locations_dubai.html">Dubai
                                     <option value="locations_durban.html">Durban
                                    <option value="locations_genoa.html">Genoa
                                   <option value="locations_gsc.html">Global Support Centre
                                    <option value="locations_hochiminh.html">Ho Chi Minh City
                                    <option value="locations_hong-kong.html">Hong Kong
                                    <option value="locations_houston.html">Houston
                                    <option value="locations_jakarta.html">Jakarta
                                    <option value="locations_kuala-lumpur.html">KualaLumpur
                                    <option value="locations_limassol.html">Limassol
                                    <option value="locations_london.html">London
                                    <option value="locations_lowestoft.html">Lowestoft
                                    <option value="locations_manila.html">Manila
                                    <option value="locations_miami.html">Miami
                                    <option value="locations_moscow.html">Moscow
                                    <option value="locations_mumbai.html">Mumbai
                                    <option value="locations_new-delhi.html">New Delhi
                                    <option value="locations_niteroi.html">Niteroi
                                    <option value="locations_oslo.html">Oslo
                                    <option value="locations_perth.html">Perth
                                    <option value="locations_riga.html">Riga
                                    <option value="locations_shanghai.html">Shanghai
                                    <option value="locations_singapore.html">Singapore
                                    <option value="locations_southampton.html">Southampton
                                    <option value="locations_tokyo.html">Tokyo
                                    <option value="locations_vancouver.html">Vancouver

                                  </select>
```

Comment: I think you need to modify the code you have posted here to be a bit clearer.

Comment: It just needed code formatting.

Comment: Can you describe the behavior you are expecting, and then behavior you are actually getting?

Comment: its wroking fine on IE6 IE7 and IE8 but not working on mozilla and google chrome and opera...its like if i select any option the page gets reloaded...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me in firefox 3.6.10

Comment: The code as posted is designed to redirect to the selected page, and it does that as expected in FireFox 3.6. I have asked a follow-up question as a comment of what is the expected behavior, and the actual behavior.  We need more clarification on this question...

Comment: So if you select Tokoyo it will change the options to a list of x from the document?

Answer (score 0):

This might work better:

```
onchange="window.location.href = this.value;"
```

Also, close all your option tags to have better HTML, some browsers might not like it.

Comment: @girishankar - worked just fine for me right now in Chrome, using your exact code. So please explain better what you mean by "not working", start by explaining what should happen vs. what actually happens.